# How can i send a reset password link with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send reset password link to user who forget passwords with codeigniter. Everything run well, however it return me with an error which is

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: http://localhost/ucuztoptan/giris/mail_sifreyenile/AUc20agxnSZL/onurcck@gmail.com

Filename: controllers/Giris.php

...
```

Here are my code regarding it

```
public function farklisifre()
    {
        $viewData = new StdClass();
        $viewData->viewFolder = $this->viewFolder;
        $viewData->subViewFolder = "sifremiunuttum";

        $email = $this->input->post("email");

        $this->load->helper("string");
        $temp_password = random_string("alnum", 12);


        $link=base_url()."giris/mail_sifreyenile/".$temp_password."/". $email;

            if($email){

                $config = array(

                    "protocol"   => "smtp",
                    "smtp_host"  => "mail.avantajsepetim.com",
                    "smtp_port"  => "587",
                    "smtp_user"  => "noreply@avantajsepetim.com",
                    "smtp_pass"  => "Ocec8687icsc@",
                    "starttls"   => true,
                    "charset"    => "utf-8",
                    "mailtype"   => "html",
                    "wordwrap"   => true,
                    "newline"    => "\r\n"
                );

                $this->load->library("email", $config);

                $this->email->from("noreply@avantajsepetim.com", "Avantajsepetim");
                $this->email->to($email);
                $this->email->subject("Şifre Yenileme");
                $this->email->message("Aşağıdaki bağlantıya tıklayarak, açılacak olan sayfadan şifrenizi yenileyebilirsiniz.</br> <a href='${$link}'> $link</a> ");



                $send = $this->email->send();

                if ($send) {

                    $bilgi="Şifre güncelleme mailiniz gönderilmiştir.";
                    $viewData->bilgi = $bilgi;
                    $this->load->view("{$viewData->viewFolder}/{$viewData->subViewFolder}/index", $viewData);



                } else {

                    $bilgi = "Mail gönderme esnasında bir hata ile karşılaşıldı.";
                    $viewData->bilgi = $bilgi;
                    $this->load->view("{$viewData->viewFolder}/{$viewData->subViewFolder}/index", $viewData);

                }


            }

}
```

The problem is this line. I use codeigniter as you know. I cant solve this so far. Everything work fine but and weird i face this error...

```
                $this->email->message("Aşağıdaki bağlantıya tıklayarak, açılacak olan sayfadan şifrenizi yenileyebilirsiniz.</br> <a href='${$link}'> $link</a> ");
```

Comment: What happends if you git rid of the link?

Comment: Weird. PHP reports the name of the variable. Why has it not done so in this example?

Comment: The problem is exactly ```<a href='${$link}'> $link</a>```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct it as follows

```
$message = "Aşağıdaki bağlantıya tıklayarak, açılacak olan sayfadan şifrenizi yenileyebilirsiniz.
            </br><a href='".$link."'>".$link."</a>";
$this->email->message($message);
```

You have an issue with the concatenation of the variable with the string.

What I suggest is that sending information like an email address is not appreciated. Sensitive information should not be visible in the URLs. 
Instead, store the generated temporary password in a separate field dedicated to the forgot password in the database and pass that in URL.

When the user clicks on the link you have to validate the temp password with the one which is already stored in the database. Once the user resets his password you have clear the temp password from the database.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I already did all of yours! The real password does not appear whic one is temp password then any user done with url which already delete itself. Thak you for your solution

Comment: Glad that helped you. Please accept and upvote my answer to help the community users